# Material Derivative of the Gradient of a Scalar Field

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vector-analysis

Let $f$ be a scalar field that is continuous and does not vary along the flow, that is $D_t(f)=0$ where $D_t=\partial_t+\vec u\cdot\nabla$ where $\vec u$ is the incompressible velocity field (i.e $\text{div}(\vec u)=0$). I am to show that for this $f$, $D_t(\vec \omega\cdot\nabla f)=0$ where $\vec\omega=\text{curl}(\vec u)$.

I am able to simplify this using Einstein Summation notation to be $D_t(\vec\omega\cdot\nabla f)=(\vec\omega\cdot\nabla \vec u)\cdot\nabla f$ by using the fact that $D_t\,\vec \omega=\vec\omega\cdot\nabla\vec u-\vec\omega\,\text{div}(\vec u)$.

What I get hung up on is the step where you must find $D_t(\nabla f)$. It seems to me that this should be identical to $\nabla D_tf$. Obviously this is incorrect, but I don't understand why...

Thank you for any replies

Comment: Does $u$ depend on $t$?

Comment: Yes. $u=u(x,t)$

Comment: @user7530 [FYI](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at a concrete example:
$$f(x) = x; \quad u(x) = x$$
in 1D. A particle that begins at $x_0$ at $t=0$ will advect to $x(t) = \frac{1}{2}(x_0+t)^2$ after time $t$.

Now $D_t\nabla f$ asks: from the point of view of a moving particle, how quickly is $\nabla f$ changing? Intuitively, since $\nabla f$ is constant, it *shouldn't matter* how the particle moves at all: the particle will always see an unchanging gradient. And indeed
$$(\nabla f)(x(t)) = 1; \quad \frac{d}{dt}(\nabla f)(x(t))\Big\vert_{t\to 0} = 0.$$

On the other hand $\nabla D_t f$ first asks a neighborhood of particles, "how quickly is $f$ changing," and then takes the gradient of the answer over the neighborhood in space. Even though $\nabla f$ is constant, because *the particles themselves are moving* at different speeds they will not agree on the speed of $f$, and so $D_t f$ is not constant over space: particles to the left will think $f$ is changing more slowly than particles to the right; and the larger the value of $x_0$, the larger the disparity. This is borne out in the calculations:
$$f(x(t)) = \frac{1}{2}(x_0+t)^2; \quad \frac{d}{dt}f(x(t))\Big\vert_{t\to 0} = x_0,$$
hence
$$\nabla D_t f = 1 \neq 0 = D_t \nabla f.$$

Now looking at the abstract formulas, $\nabla$ commutes with differentiation in $t$, but not with the advection term;

\begin{align*}
\nabla D_t f &= D_t \nabla f - u \cdot \nabla\nabla f + \nabla(u\cdot \nabla f)\\
&= D_t\nabla f + \nabla u \cdot \nabla f + u \times \mathrm{curl}(\nabla f)-\mathrm{curl}(u) \times \nabla f\\
&= D_t\nabla f + \nabla u \cdot \nabla f -\mathrm{curl}(u) \times \nabla f.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. I did not think of it that way.

Comment: I see something I am not sure is correct though, how can you take the inner product of $\vec u$ and the Laplacian of $f$? That is, $\vec u\cdot\nabla^2 f$ is meaningless since $\vec u$ is a vector and $\nabla^2 f$ is a scalar.

Comment: @NathanielWerner by $\nabla^2$ I mean the gradient of the gradient, not the Laplacian. I've replaced with $\nabla \nabla$ in case that's clearer.

Comment: ok I see now, I have always seen the Laplacian as $\nabla^2$ but my math professors assure me that it is more commonplace to use $\Delta$ among mathematicians.